# How can I mass insert multiple rows in MySQL with two unique columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, unique

i'm working on a webpage indexing robot and using php and mysql. one of the tables will be to store the list of webpages. i want that table to have an integer based `id` column (so that i can join it to other tables more quickly, and so that other tables can reference it without storing the complete url in a column), but i also want the `url` column to remain unique.

the reason this question has come up is that if my script reads a web page that has 250 links i'm not sure the best way to add them to the webpages table without creating duplicates. i could loop the 250 links that i found and query the table for each of them to make sure they don't exist, and then insert the ones that do -  which would require at least 250 queries.

however, if i could have mysql enforce the `url` to be a unique column i could simply do one `insert ignore`, statement with all of the links. this would keep the existing records from being duplicated while adding new ones. if i had this type of table with an integer id column that is unique / primary and auto-incremented, could i also specify that the url column be unique?

```
  id (auto inc)     url                            added
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                 http://site.com/page-a/        2010-01-01 01:23:34
  2                 http://site.com/page-b/        2010-01-01 01:23:34
  3                 http://site.com/page-c/        2010-01-01 01:23:34
```

another option that has crossed my mind is setting the url to be a unique primary key, and then manually incrementing the `id` column with php / mysql statements:

```
url (unique, primary)         id          added
-------------------------------------------------------------
http://site.com/page-a/       1           2010-01-01 01:23:34
http://site.com/page-b/       2           2010-01-01 01:23:34
http://site.com/page-c/       3           2010-01-01 01:23:34
```

it seems like that would have the benefit of allowing mysql to enforce a unique url column (and thus allowing my `insert ignore` method), and also allowing me to join on an integer. the only weird thing is having to rely on my script to add and increment the id column, but i may be willing to do that if there is not a better option.

what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make the `url` column unique. So a big `INSERT IGNORE INTO ... (...) VALUES (...), (...), ...` will do the job.

Do **NOT** make `url` primary though! Your primary key should be the `id` auto_increment field; simply create a unique index on the `url` field.

Don't forget that `INSERT IGNORE` is MySQL-specific though so if you ever plan to support e.g PostgreSQL, too, your code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many `UNIQUE` indexes as you like, but only one `PRIMARY` one (which is why it's called primary).

Auto Increment in MySQL, however, only works on `PRIMARY` keys. So you should have your `id` column `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY`, and your `url` column `UNIQUE`. `PRIMARY` also implies `UNIQUE` so you don't need to and shouldn't add both on a single column.